# Generate task module without a button click in ms teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I need to invoke a Task Module in Waterfall step of Dialog in Bot Framework without any button click. Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not supported. You will need an action from the user to invoke the task module in Microsoft Teams. Depending on your scenario you could possibly solve it by sending an Adaptive Card with a form, however this will limit you in the features for user interaction.

Task modules can be invoked in three ways:

- **Channel or personal tabs.** Using the Microsoft Teams Tabs SDK you can invoke task modules from **buttons, links or menus on your tab**. This is covered in detail here.
- **Bots.** Buttons on cards sent from your bot. This is particularly useful when you don't need everyone in a channel to see what you are doing with a bot. For example, when having users respond to a poll in a channel it's not terribly useful to see a record of that poll being created. This is covered in detail here.
- **Outside of Teams from a deep link.** You can also create URLs to invoke a task module from anywhere. This is covered in detail here.

Source: [What are task modules?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules)

Comment: Thanks @mick.  I see this post is a year old, just checking to see if this has changed, or if there is still no direct way to open a TaskModule from my bot? Thanks!